# Wordpress plugin ignoring wptexturize, but I want smart quotes/apostrophes

Tags: wordpress, plugins, blogs, smart-quotes

A website I'm working on uses Advanced Excerpt (https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-excerpt/). I'd like all of the website to have smart quotation marks and apostrophes instead of straight ones, but the plugin seems to be ignoring wptexturize.

Is there a way force the plugin to use wptexturize? Or a code I can use to force smart quotes and quotations in a different way?